# jQuery Mobile - Javascript not executing when app launched from Home Screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is driving me crazy.  I'm working on a .NET MVC3 application that uses jQuery Mobile 1.1 and am testing on my iPhone 4S.  I make javascript changes and FTP the .js files to my server and go to the page in safari on my phone and see the changes.  But when I launch the app from the Home Screen shortcut, the javascript changes are not reflected.

I've deleted the icon, cleared my cache, cookies, etc. and can't get it to work.

Has anyone seen this before?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What the script? What event do you used? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Just my own script.  It's just like it's cached somehow.  I even deleted the script from the server, and the app is still working as if it's there.  Again, but ONLY when launched from the home screen.  Going to the URL in safari now breaks because the .js file has been deleted.

Comment: Update:  This morning I launched my app from the home screen and all of the javascript worked as expected.  So, it certainly appears to be a caching issue.  Could it be an IIS setting?  But it doesn't cache when viewing in Safari.  I don't get it, but glad to know that it will work if I wait long enough.